# DC.js - Composite Chart - Fill between lines

Tags: dc.js

I was wondering if there was a way to compose a chart that has 3 lines to effectively create a threshold / band around the core data:

Line 1-shows the actual core data points
Line 2-shows an upper line that is n above the core
Line 3-shows a lower line that is n below the core

The Core data would be an line without area fill but I would like to fill the area between 2&3 to show the n behind the core.

I tried adding additional lines and setting the colour on the lower line to transparent but the upper line draws over.

```
speedSumGroup       = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run;}),
  speedSumGroupUpper    = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return (d.Speed * d.Run) + 1000;}),
  speedSumGroupLower = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return (d.Speed * d.Run) - 1000;})
  ;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stutraystu/80p1et45/1/)

**EDIT 1**:
See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stutraystu/9e1qctwb/23/) using a Stacked Line with the d3 StackLayout parameters set as order=Ascending / Offset=Expand.
The issue now is that nasty leftover area fill at the bottom.
The reason I used Expand is because it applies the correct y Values.
If I could somehow use Wiggle but force the data to plot on the same y axis instead of stacking then we're (almost) onto a winner.

Comment: This has been discussed a few times. I am optimistic that it's possible using a custom stacking algorithm, but I haven't found the exact thing. Here is one reference: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/581 - also streamgraphs are possible as of dc 3.0 https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1375

Comment: If it's not clear, I'm suggesting that you look at the stacked chart, not the composite, since visually that's more like what you want - composite doesn't work well with area, as you mention. Stacking will require transforming your data somewhat, but that's easier than changing the way charts are drawn.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'll have a look at the stacked and see how I get on.